# change the font style using check box

Tags: c#, visual-studio, task, text-editor, windows-forms-designer

hi I want to change the text font of text in rich text box to bold, italic, underline. I have the following code. But if i click another check box,the first check box change disappear. May I know how to fix it

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            richTextBox1.Font = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);


    }

    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         richTextBox1.Font = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
    }

    private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Font = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
    }

    private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Font = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to call a method like this from the checkBox_CheckedChanged

```
private void UpdateFont()
{
    System.Drawing.FontStyle style = System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular;
    if (checkBox1.Checked) style |= System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold;
    if (checkBox2.Checked) style |= System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic;
    if (checkBox3.Checked) style |= System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline;
    textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, style);
}
```

Comment: can u pls share me the code to set the style based on the checked checkbox

Comment: I edited the answer

Comment: its perfectly working....

Comment: If i make bold and save the file then if i try to open the saved file i cant see the changes i made.what are the changes i have to do in ma implementation ?